# Idiomatic way to count the number of distinct objects of recursively-defined custom type

Tags: dictionary, recursion, go, set, equality

As I understand it, I cannot define equality for user-defined types in Go. So what would be the idiomatic way of computing the number of distinct objects of some custom type (possibly recursively defined). Here is an example of the kind of thing I am trying to do.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type tree struct {
    left  *tree
    right *tree
}

func shapeOf(a tree) string {
    temp := "{"
    if a.left != nil {
        temp += shapeOf(*(a.left))
    }
    temp += "}{"
    if a.right != nil {
        temp += shapeOf(*(a.right))
    }
    temp += "}"
    return temp;
}

func main() {
    a := tree{nil, nil}
    b := tree{nil, &a}

    c := tree{nil, nil}
    d := tree{nil, &c}

    e := tree{nil, nil}
    f := tree{&e, nil}

    s := make(map[string]bool)

    s[shapeOf(b)] = true
    s[shapeOf(d)] = true
    s[shapeOf(f)] = true
    fmt.Println(len(s)) // As required, prints 2 because the first two trees have the same shape
}
```

It works, but the use of strings is extremely ugly, and probably inefficient too. Obviously I could easily write a recursive method to tell if two trees are equal - something like

```
func areEqual(a, b tree) bool
```

but this wouldn't enable me to use trees as map keys. What is the idiomatic Go way to do something like this?

Comment: Typically if you're making a complex object a key of a map-like structure, you need *both* a hash function, and an equality function. Go doesn't provide this out of the box but there's no way you'd only write one function for it anyway.

However, if you want to be somewhat more idiomatic/efficient then I'd suggest using []byte or bytes.Buffer instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define equality for user-defined type because it is already defined by go. Basically, all there is to know about it is explained in the [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) section.

Short story: two struct values can be compared if their fields can be compared (no slice, map or function). And same thing for equality: two structs are equal if their fields are equal. In your case, the problem is that for comparing pointers, Golang compares the memory addresses, not the struct they point to.

So, is this possible to count distinct values of a certain struct ? Yes, if the struct contain no nested slice, map, function or pointer. For recursive types, that's not possible because you cannot define something like this:

```
type tree struct {
    left tree
    right tree
}
```

The idiomatic way of testing the equality of recursive types is to use `reflect.DeepEqual(t1, t2 interface{})` as it follows indirections. However, this method is inefficient because uses heavy reflection. In your case, I do not think there is any clean and elegant solution to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That's the confirmation I needed. I wasn't aware of `reflect.DeepEqual`. If there was also a `DeepHash` I could write my own hashtable implementation for arbitrary types.